# Angular cli adding external lib

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

So I am trying to add lodash to fresh project based on angular cli. I've made it 
on morning and it worked brilliant. But now I'am getting:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0 caused by: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_lodash__.fill is not a function
```

Since I am using fresh angular cli

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.20-4
node: 6.2.1
os: win32 x64
```

I've only installed lodash:

```
 npm install lodash --save
 npm install @types/lodash --save-dev

 #angular-cli.json

 "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/lodash/lodash.js"
  ],
```

and added in code:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
export class AppComponent {
   title = 'app works!' + _.fill(Array(3), 2);
}
```

So what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add it as a global script, just import it in the module that you need it and that's it. If you import it both as a global JS and then as an import in a module, it will override itself.

More info here:
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/12/External-JavaScript-dependencies-in-Typescript-and-Angular-2

Comment: I just wonder one thing more. What are diffrences between lodash and jquery ? Cause on wiki is said to add jqury to angular-cli.json

Comment: I presume you're asking what is the difference in _importing_ rather than the libraries itself. Well the wiki example is with _jQuery_ because if you want to use another _global_ 3rd party library like _Bootstrap_ it won't work properly. _Bootstrap_ has a dependency on _jQuery_ and when it will load, it will throw an error if it doesn't find a global window object jQuery. Hope it makes sense

Comment: Yep exactly, but what in case when bootstrap has dependency to lodash ? So then I should put lodash in angular-cli.json which will break build ?

Comment: well there are multiple approaches, the easiest one is just declare lo-dash as a global script in angular-cli, then you must declare lo-dash as type any, something like this `let lodash: any (or let _: any)` and just use it as is (without importing). But keep in mind that things will change when angular-cli is released.